# Outlook may not be installed with a newer version of Outlook

Tags: installation, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010

Encountered this error while setting up Office on a virtual machine today, I am trying to installed the 32bit version of Outlook.

This is a fresh VM install so I **know** outlook is not already installed but I have verified this to make sure no light versions of outlook came preinstalled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the issue was because I had already installed the  [Microsoft Exchange Server MAPI Client and Collaboration Data Objects 1.2.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=1004) for Software Developement testing, for some reason this blocks the installation of outlook.

Opening Programs and Features and uninstalling the `Collaboration and Data Objects` allowed the installation of Outlook to proceed.

The Collaboration and Data Objects could not be reinstalled after the installation of Outlook, it seems they do not play well together.

Comment: For me it was called `Microsoft Messaging API and Collaboration Data Objects 1.2.1`